# get all row entries based on month/year in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with the following structure and I am trying to get all rows from this table based on passing both the month and year using a where on the timestamp column (this will be a unix standard timestamp)

```
e.g month - 3, year - 2018 // get all rows for March 2018 only.

// db structure
id, timestamp, post_title
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want rows for a given month using a unix timestamp, I would recommend:

```
where timestamp >= unix_timestamp('2018-03-01') and
      timestamp < unix_timestamp('2018-04-01')
```

If you are passing in a variable, I would recommend passing in the first day of the month and doing:

```
where timestamp >= unix_timestamp(?) and
      timestamp < unix_timestamp(? + interval 1 month)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use convert function

```
SELECT  * FROM dbo.YourTable WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),DATEPART(mm,timestamp))+'-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),DATEPART(yy,timestamp)) ='3-2018'
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this can help you.

SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2;